# Is it necessary to call super() when creating a child class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just learned about object oriented programming in python, and there was something that didn't make sense to me.

```
# 1st example

class Bird:
    def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

    def fly(self):
        print(f"{self.name.title()} is flying.")

class Penguin(Bird):
    def fly(self):
         print("A penguin can't fly.")


a_penguin = Penguin('rico')
print(a_penguin.name)
a_penguin.fly()


# 2nd example
class Bird:
    def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

    def fly(self):
        print(f"{self.name.title()} is flying.")

class Penguin(Bird):
    def __init__(self, name):
    super().__init__(name)

    def fly(self):
         print("A penguin can't fly.")


a_penguin = Penguin('rico')
print(a_penguin.name)
a_penguin.fly()
```

Both of examples above do the same thing, and my question is that is it necessary to call super() when creating child class ?

Comment: If you don't call `super().__init__(name)`, the superclass's `__init__` method won't be called, and the name in your instance will not be initialised. Whether you want that or not is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

If your `__init__()` function doesn't do *anything at all different* from the superclass's version, then it should be fine for you to omit it - like any other method, the subclass will inherit the superclass's implementation.

However, if your `__init__()` function did more stuff, then you'd want to call the superclass's `__init__()` and then do your class's additional stuff:

```
class Bird:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def fly(self):
        print(f"{self.name.title()} is flying.")

    def run(self):
        print(f"{self.name.title()} is walking.")

class Ostrich(Bird):
    def __init__(self, name, speed):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.speed = speed

    def fly(self):
        print(f"An ostrich cannot fly.")

    def run(self):
        print(f"{self.name.title()} is running at {self.speed} kph!")
```